# How to convert CvMat to Numpy array?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Looking to convert a CvMat to numpy array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [OpenCV Python Cookbook](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/cookbook.html#numpy-and-opencv):

```
>>> import cv, numpy                       # Comments added by me
>>> mat = cv.CreateMat(3, 5, cv.CV_32FC1)  # make a 3x5 mat
>>> cv.Set(mat, 7)                         # set the cells to 7
>>> a = numpy.asarray(mat)                 # convert it to a numpy array
>>> print a
[[ 7.  7.  7.  7.  7.]
 [ 7.  7.  7.  7.  7.]
 [ 7.  7.  7.  7.  7.]]
```

Here is the [`numpy.asarray` documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html).